# How do i replace empty space from one file with a group (regex known) from another file?

Tags: regex, sed

I have linux. I want to copy a group from one file to another at the same position (currently occupied by space). My regex is known and is `[^\d ][00]\.\w*+`

I have not tried anything as i am noob and i only used a dataset and run a program to get my regex.

Example:

```
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      20.704  64.205 -29.116  0.00  0.00           N
```

and

```
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      20.704  64.205 -29.116  0.00  0.00    +0.229 N
```

As described i just want to do simple copy paste of the +0.229 group (per regex defined). I have python and R at disposal atm, as well as all standard linux packages.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: If you know the position, why do you need regex? What do you intend by `[00]` and `*+` in your regex?

Comment: ok. fair point. i can also just choose from x to y and replace. But which program should i use for it? R? 

There are multiple values with a lot of variables. The regex is fine i just didnt upload all the text. But character position is always the same. I would know how to do it in C sharp but i stopped using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU `sed` like below:

```
sed -i 's/^.\{70\}/&+0.229/' file
```

`^` matches the start of a string, `.\{70\}` matches any 70 characters. The `&` is the whole match value that you append `+0.229` to.